# Encontrar ocorrências de uma palavra

Tags: php, string

Eu tenho um texto e gostaria de encontrar certas palavras, mas na maneira como estou a fazer que é com o  `substr_count()` só consigo encontrar a palavra tal como eu a escrevi.

Exemplo

```
$text = "Eu sou um Menino e gosto de brincar com outros MENINOS";
$count= substr_count($text , 'menino');
echo $count;
```

O resultado disto vai dar `0` porque como a função é `case sensitive` não me vai encontrar as outras palavras, a maneira de contornar isto?

Comment: Você pode deixar a pesquisa e a string em caixa baixa ou alta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra evitar o `case sensitive` basta você transformar ambas `strings` em letras maiúsculas ou minusculas, exemplo:

```
$count= substr_count(strtoupper($text), strtoupper("menino"));
```

Dessa forma sua frase vai virar:

```
"EU SOU UM MENINO E GOSTO DE BRINCAR COM OUTROS MENINOS"
```

E seu outro argumento vira:

```
"MENINO"
```

> 2 ocorrências

### [IdeOne Exemplo](https://ideone.com/sNt5KO)