# Como contar a quantidade de vezes que uma palavra se repete em uma frase?

Tags: php

Tenho uma [determinada frase](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35026739#35026739) declarada numa variável. Veja:

```
$bacco = "Você tem que abrir seu coração pro SQL e pedir o que realmente quer.";
```

Eu consigo verificar se existe uma determinada palavra dentro da frase usando [strpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php), desta forma:

```
if (strpos($bacco, 'que') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Como posso verificar a quantidade de vezes que a palavra "que" se repete nesta frase?

Comment: `str_split` com a palavra desejada precedida e seguida de um espaço, ocorrências = tamanho do array - 1.

Comment: Deve retornar 2 apenas certo? o `quer` entra ou não na contagem?

Comment: @rray por isso que a palavra deve ser precedida/seguida de um espaço (' que ').

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Como retornar palavras mais comuns de um texto com PHP?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22855/3635) / [Encontrar ocorrências de uma palavra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71649/3635)

Comment: Desculpa @rray não vi a pergunta. `quer` não pode entrar na lista.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode usar uma regex para procurar a palavra exata usando o termo procurado entra a ancora `\b` a [função preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) retorna o número ocorrências capturadas, no caso duas uma vez que `quer` ou `qualquer` não devem entrar na contagem.

Se precisa manipular os elementos capturados informe o terceiro argumento na chamada da função:

```
$str = "Você tem que abrir seu coração pro SQL e pedir o que realmente quer qualque."; 
$contagem = preg_match_all('/\bque\b/i', $str);
echo $contagem;
```

Ou ainda:

```
$str = "Você tem que abrir seu coração pro SQL e pedir o que realmente quer qualque."; 
preg_match_all('/\bque\b/i', $str, $ocorrencias);
echo count($ocorrencias[0]);
```

Caso deseje ver tudas as capturas faça: `print_r($ocorrencias);`

**Relacionada:**

[Pra que serve um boundary \b numa expressão regular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/91)

Answer (score 9):

O PHP já tem função pronta para isso:

```
$ack = "Você tem que abrir seu coração pro SQL e pedir o que realmente quer."; 
echo substr_count ( $ack, 'que' );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/odUsu2)**.

Se não quiser contar o `que` da palavra `quer`, basta por espaços:

```
echo substr_count( ' '.$frase.' ', ' '.$palavra.' ' );
```

No caso:

```
echo substr_count( ' '.$ack.' ', ' que ' );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/cYI6xk)**.

Se quiser que maiúsculas e minúsculas não façam diferença:

```
echo substr_count( mb_strtoupper($ack), mb_strtoupper('que') );
```

Claro que neste caso, pode usar a técnica dos espaços também.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-count.php

Comment: Mal posso ver seus movimentos